# Appropriate Use of Possessive Plurals?

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives

We have a debate on whether it should be "classes" or "classes'" in the sentence below. Your wisdom is appreciated.

Sentence:
*This rebalancing of customer **classes’** impacts on the system means there will be uneven impacts to rates the first year.*

For reference, there are five customer classes (e.g. residential, non-residential, etc.) being referenced in the sentence.
Thanks for your feedback!
Aaron

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct#English

Comment: Grammar **requires** the possessive indicator. Why the question?

Comment: @MikeGraham I don't think a plural makes a good noun adjunct.

Comment: @Kris so... you'd suggest... *rephrasing?* :P

Comment: @KrisW There's no question in the post *per se*. Nothing needs done.

Comment: @Kris -- did you check out the article?

Comment: Thank you for your perspectives! I appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

The quoted example is gramatically correct, but poorly written.

The reason for this, and your confusion, is the word "impacts": it can be read as both a noun (the effects of the thing) and a verb (creates an effect). The sentence, as written, forces your reader back-track and re-parse your sentence to see if "impacts" is a functioning as a verb or noun (apostrophes are easily missed, and often misused).

To prevent your meaning being carried by a tiny punctuation mark, I would suggest this re-wording:

- This rebalancing of the impacts of customer classes on on the system means there will be uneven impacts **on** rates the first year.

Note also that one cannot have an impact *to* something, only *on* or *upon* that thing. It's also pretty poor writing to use "impacts" twice in once sentence - "effects" is probably the noun you're looking for for in one of the two cases.

Comment: Rephrasing is not an answer, though.

Comment: The first sentence of my post is my answer: the possessive apostrophe *is* needed in the sentence. That answers the OP's question.

After that, I try to explain why OP has got themselves into this confusion, and a way out of it.

Comment: Thank you for your perspectives! I appreciate it!